# YouTube not working on 32 Bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a 32 Bit PC. For the past two or three days neither of my browsers (Firefox & Chromium) is able to play Youtube.

I see this message:

[image]

"pubads.g.doubleclick.net refused to connect"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Googling pubads doubleclick net refused to connect seems to suggest is some type of ad-ware, do you have any add-ons installed? Did you try with Firefox safe mode or a fresh profile?

Answer (score -1):

The 32-bit of these browsers and the back-porting to 14.04 is pretty limited. My guess is that at some point some sunset dates on various technologies like what types of ciphers used to encrypt the HTTPS connection have passed and now those ciphers or certificate algorithms are no longer allowed by the server.

If you open the Inspector and go to Console (in both Firefox or Chrome it's almost the same) and try to load the page you should see an error or warning in the console explaining what support is no longer present.

It's a real pain too because 32-bit systems are left mostly just needing to be updated to 64-bit systems, even if they don't use more than 4GB of RAM etc. It's mostly because developers don't want to support both 32-bit and 64-bit and package managers also don't want to.

**EDIT** If you think this answer is wrong please explain why. I have multiple 32-bit systems I very much want the browser supported, but they aren't.